# How select multiple columns in `lm` in R?

Tags: r, regression

Are there any convenient way to select a lot of columns in `lm`?

I know linear regression can be done in the following way

```
lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+...+xn)
```

Can I do something like deselect columns? For example, I don't want the 'x1,x2,x3,x4' in the model but I want the rest. Are there anyway similar to `select(-x1,-x2,-x3,-4)`?

Comment: For the most flexible control during runtime over which variables are used, either construct the formula programmatically (see the help for `as.formula`) or construct the model matrix (see the help for `model.matrix`) and manipulate it.  These two strategies generally work in most regression software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
lm(y ~ ., data = data[, -c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4")])
```

This uses all the available variables plus an intercept. You could filter your data frame first to keep only the variable you want in the model.